# Ctrl-enter for fish shell

Tags: bash, shell, fish, escape-characters

I had tried to create some accept completion and execute right away combination in fish on pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
function fish_user_key_bindings
    bind \c\n accept-autosuggestion execute
end
```

Unfortunately this attempt fails. Looks like fish doesn't like two escaped chars:

```
#bind -a
...
bind \\c\\n accept-autosuggestion execute
```

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> doesn't make any sense. The <kbd>enter</kbd> key normally sends a carriage-return; `\r`, aka `\cM`. In other words, <kbd>enter</kbd> is already a control character. So applying the `\c` modifier does’t make any sense. In fact, this should cause Fish to generate an error so I’ll open an issue to remind the team to fix that.

Also, you were trying to bind `\c\n`. Binding `\n` (aka `\cJ`) works for Fish 2.2.0 or earlier. But as of 2.3.0 you won’t get the expected result because fish now disables the TTY driver’s `icrnl` mode. So Fish will receive the `\r` (aka `\cM`) character normally sent by the <kbd>enter</kbd> key. So you really want to bind `\r` (or `\cM`). Of course that doesn’t change the fact that that `\c\cM` doesn’t make any sense.

Comment: [Github issue 3162](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/3162) opened to track enhancing fish to warn about doing non-sensical things like applying the `\c` modifier to a control character.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you missed only the `''` in the bind command line.

Indeed the simple `bind \c\n accept-autosuggestion execute` generates the error:

> bind: Expected zero or two parameters, got 3

Adding `''` around the command it seems to works

```
function fish_user_key_bindings
    bind \c\n 'accept-autosuggestion execute'
end
```

After the bind command execution with `bind -a` gives me

> bind \x1cn 'accept-autosuggestion execute'

Comment: Well, just try it without the execute in the end. Ctrl-return is just not recognized that way, whatever you put in the end. Also quoting \c\n is of no help. And when I just pick any other combination, e.g. \cn, it also works without quoting the both commands.

Comment: @Michael I needed to quote the _composite command_ because `bind` wants 0 or 2 parameters and when 2, the second is the action. You can check in `bind -a`. I cannot answer now if you can bind ctrl enter. I tried to bind as action `'echo ; echo ; echo '` to ctrl-a and it works. Please add the version of fish you are using...

Comment: I'm using 2.2.0. Again, \cn or \ca whatever, works fine for me, using qouting for the commands or not, the command is executed. Maybe your version is outdated here? Anyways, binding ctrl-a and referring to that is pointless,  I'm specifically talking about \c\n.

Comment: I'm using the last available for Ubuntu LTS (the 2.0.0) updated and installed this morning just for your question. BTW the problem with `<Ctrl-Enter>` is that it depends on the terminal you are using: some terminals send `<NL>` when `<C-Enter>` is pressed. Some others `< ^M>` as for the simple `<Enter>`. See [1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/598404/3569208) and [2](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/63887/66388). Check your terminal, maybe inside a bash with `<Ctrl-V>` and after `<Enter>` and `<Ctrl-Enter>`

Comment: Downvote without any comment IMHO are useless... At least let us know what do you think is wrong or unclear...